# Finding the density function of $X + Y$ given the joint density function $f(x,y) = x + y$

Tags: probability, density-function

> Suppose $X$ and $Y$ have the joint density function
>   $f(x,y) = x + y$ for  $0 < x <  1$, $ 0 < y <  1$.
>   If $Z = X + Y$, then $Z$ has the density function (______)?

I try it as follow but that's not the answer the book gives:

$$Pr(Z<z)=H(z)=\iint_{\Omega}{x+y}\,dy\,dx\\ 
\Omega:{x\in(0,1),\,y\in(0,1),\,x+y\le z}$$
$$H(z)  = \int_0^z[xy+1/2y^2]_0^{z-x}\,dx \\
 = \int_0^z[x(z-x)+1/2(z-x)^2]\,dx \\
 = 1/2\int_0^z{z^2-x^2}\,dx
 =1/2[z^2x-1/3x^3]_{x=0}^z \\
 =1/2[z^3-1/3z^3] \\
 =1/3z^3$$

so $$h(z)=H'(z)=z^2$$
but why is there another branch?

[image]

ps: The book's answer is:[image: the given ans]

Comment: If you've integrated out $x$ and $y$, how is it still there???? And note that if $z=1/2$, your integral would include negative $y$. Draw a picture of the support of the distribution, and the set you want to integrate over. Then, write down the integral and do it.

Comment: Please learn MathJax. Handwriting is often difficult to read. Formatting tips [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just write down the probability as an integral.

$P(Z \leq z) = P(X+Y \leq z) = \iint_{x+y \leq z} f_{X,Y}(x,y) dx dy =\iint_{x+y \leq z \text{ and } 0 < x < 1 \text{ and } 0 < y <1 } (x+y) dx dy$.

Now, simply parameterize the region $\{x+y \leq z \text{ and } 0 < x < 1 \text{ and } 0 < y <1 \}$ and do the integral.

Comment: please correct my solution

Comment: I already change my integral but one trouble left.

Comment: Clearly, $Z$ takes on values between $0$ and $2$. Draw the region you need to integrate over for $P(Z\leq z)$ when $0 \leq z \leq 1$. Then, draw the region for $1 \leq z \leq 2$ (in this case, it may be slightly easier to look at $P(Z > z) = \iint_{x+y > z \text{ and } 0 < x < 1 \text{ and } 0 < y <1 } (x+y) dx dy$ and use $P(Z \leq z) = 1 - P(Z>z)$, though you could do the integral directly as written in the answer).

Comment: i try the other branch but it seems to lead wrong result.Is this integral right?

Comment: Try playing with this: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=0%3C%3Dx%3C%3D1,0%3C%3Dy%3C%3D1,+x%2By%3C%3D3%2F2 (swap 3/2 in for different values between 0 and 2). If you put z in rather than 3/2, thats the set you need to to do the integral over to find $P(Z \leq z)$.

Comment: Yes ,I know your meaning.In my photo,I set up a integral ,is that right?

Comment: I get it,the last term is not z-1,because the f is not  a constant,thanks.